# Write to or write for?

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct way to express that I am writing or I wrote a letter aimed at another person? Is it ‘I write / I wrote a letter to you’ or ‘I write / wrote a letter for you’? I’m so confused. 
Does it work the same way talking about writing, playing and dedicating songs?

Answer (score 2):

You can say “I wrote a letter **to** you” but it would be more natural to say

> I wrote you a letter.

“I wrote a letter **for** you*”
 indicates that you wrote a letter on their behalf because they couldn't do it themselves.